# Enable WinHttpRequest in Windows Firewall

Tags: firewall, windows-firewall, winhttprequest

I have a VBA code that sends a WinHttpRequest 5.1 request. It works perfectly on my home computer, but times out at work, so I believe the firewall is blocking the request. 
What is the name of the program that I need to enable in Windows Firewall to allow it to send/receive requests?